# Proof exclusive ownership of IP address

Tags: ip-address, azure

We run VM's in azure behind LB and public dedicated IP address. The customer requires proof of ownership of the dedicated IP address. Or if that's impossible, than he requires to have the ability to at least check to see if the IP address is eclusively provisioned to our VM's. When he checks the RIPE (IANA) register, he sees it is registered to Microsoft, and not to us.
What is the best way to deal with this request?

Comment: Why does the customer need this proof?     If the IP address wasn't provisioned to the VM, you wouldn't be able to get to the web site running on that VM using that IP address.

Comment: For outbound traffic, to connect to their systems, they wanna be certain that our systems are the only ones coming from that IP to connect to their infra...

Comment: Send them a screenshot of the IP address on your Azure dashboard. There is no cleaner solution to this afaik. If they don't trust your screenshots, then there is no solution short of having Microsoft themselves vouch for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The customer requires proof of ownership of the dedicated IP address.

Unless this customer is willing to pay an massive premium for you to really **own** an IP address block ([more info](https://superuser.com/q/323801)...is this a multimillion dollar enterprise contract?) and pay for the talent and hardware to manage just that part of the job, what they are really asking for is a way to demonstrate that you have **exclusive use** of a single IP address.

> Or if that's impossible, than he requires to have the ability to at least check to see if the IP address is exclusively provisioned to our VM's.

That's much easier to resolve, for example use this VirtualHost template for Apache and put a simple index.html page with a short message to the client on it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName IP.AD.DR.ESS
  DocumentRoot /var/www/something
  DirectoryIndex index.html

</VirtualHost>
```

Now they can visit the IP address directly and see proof that you control it.

I suspect that this customer does not have a good understanding of the situation, or your company is in way over it's head. Good luck resolving this matter either way. They probably copied some contract/legal boilerplate without really understanding what this would actually cost to deliver.

Answer (score -2):

When you apply for a business bar in your SSL 
they will require at 4 static ip addresses that you host your domain website on.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you mean with 'will require at 4 static ip addresses that'